# phonegap android assets code is viewable - want to convert it as unreadable

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing sample app for android using Phonegap. In assets/www/ folder all the html,css, js codes are readable when I extract .apk file. Is there any way to convert it as unreadble while being build as .apk.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript, CSS and HTML are all client side languages, and you can't really make them unreadable by "compiling". At best, you could obfuscate the code using any obfuscating service before you package it into an apk. This'll just change variable names to meaningless stuff, and remove indentation and spacing to reduce code readability, but its the best you can do for these languages.