# Phonegap iOS App source code viewable

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

This Question might be related [phonegap android assets code is viewable - want to convert it as unreadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16103778/phonegap-android-assets-code-is-viewable-want-to-convert-it-as-unreadable)

This video shows the problem I am talking about http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ixg6jmrgAU8#t=113s

I am building an ios app using Phonegap, AngularJS, html, css3. Everything works fine, I have the app.ipa file.

But if I rename the .ipa to .zip and extract the files > show package contents it shows all my source code including the assets, www folder and code in it.

I have looked at some other apps built with phonegap or hybrid apps some of them have the same view, some don't show the source code even though they are built with phonegap.

Is it something I am doing wrong ? I dont want my html, and code in js to be seen by others. This is my first hybrid app, Haven't tried this but using cordova as component in iOS application would solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different solutions to this problem.

Some of the more simple ones that I can think of would be to obfuscate your code. Tools like Google's [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), the [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/), and the like do this by minifying the code, which makes it a lot less readable, and a bit of effort to get anything out of it.

If you're looking for something a little more advanced, I came across this solution that [encrypts your Phonegap source code](http://wordpress.medicationsafetyfoundation.org/?p=578) and decrypts it on the device at runtime.

If these aren't what you're looking for, point me to a few IPAs, and I can try to figure out what they're doing differently.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. will try out the encryption solution. I was looking at all the apps on phonegap website and yes all of them have code viewable. Previously I was looking at hybrid apps on App store- not sure what else they are using. One of the apps I was looking at is living social app.